# Even after I connect my dongle no net comes

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, google-chrome, proxy

I have a tata photon plus dongle,but even after I connect my dongle to my laptop I get no internet. The IE displays "internet explorer cannot display the page" and Chrome displays "Unable to connect to proxy server".

I have checked my proxy setting and no proxy is being used and Automatically detect setting is the only thing selected. I am able to do a successful ping to google when connected with my dongle.

I tried uninstalling tata photon plus software and installing back but no use. I tried to connect the dongle using different port but no use.

I am able access internet in my system from other source like WIFI and company LAN, but when I connect my dongle no net comes.

In order to make sure my dongle works fine, I connected it to my friend lappy and he was able to access internet without issue.

I have problem in accessing net only when I connect my dongle to my laptop.

Comment: So you're able to successfully ping google but the google homepage fails to open in the browser?

Comment: Is the dongle a "3G/4G" one? The software you install creates a dial-up/network interface so you need to use the software to create the initial connection to the Internet before your browser will work... This is certainly how almost all the dongles work in the UK.. It's often called a connection manager...

Answer (score 0):

Have you gone through the network setup?  It may be that you need to setup your network.  Since you said IE, I assume that this is a windows system. In the control panel there should be a 'Network and Internet'.  Try going through that with the dongle connected.